# (Python) Slice lines till symbol from large file and append to other file - Fastest possible approach

Tags: python, regex, string, find

Need your help. I have to remove all lines till first '>' is encountered from file2  and append these lines at end of file1. Actually I have split a large file to multiple small files using linux 'split' command and some of the entries (starting with '>') got spread in two files. So, I just want to stitch such entries by copying reminder entry back to one file.

Example File1:

```
>1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
CGGGGGGGGGGGGG
DEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Example File2:

```
AFGGGGGGGGGGGG
DEEEEEEEEEEE
>2
AAAABBBBBBBBB
DFFFFFFFFFFFFF
DFFFFFFFSSSS
```

In above example, File2 has first two lines that belong to File1 and therefore need to be removed from File2 and appended at end of File1.

One way to do this could be:

```
fh1 = open(file1,'a')
fh2 = open(file2, 'r+')
filelist2 = file2.split('>')
string = filelist2[0]
fh1.write(string)
<SOME WAY TO REMOVE LINES TILL SYMBOL FROM FILE1>
fh1.close()
fh2.close()
```

I know there could be several ways to achieve this but problem is that both files are large ~600MB. Also, this is to be done on 4~10 files through a loop. So, I am looking for the most efficient and fastest approach and therefore need your suggestions.

Awaiting your suggestions

AK

Comment: I tried to read your question many times but I do not still understand anything..

Comment: @Antii: Sorry if post was not clear I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to reconstruct sequences from a FASTA file that was split at arbitrary line numbers. The best solution would be to split them at sequences boundaries in the first place. Using [pyfasta](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfasta/):

```
$ pyfasta split -n 6 original.fasta
```

According to the documentation, this splits original.fasta into 6 files of relatively even size.

Following your edit, you can probably also use `csplit` instead of `split`:

```
csplit -zk original.fasta "/^>/+<offset>" "{*}"
```

The offset is a number of lines that will be skipped when looking for the regular expression (without it you would split each sequence into an individual file). You can play with the value according to your desired file length.

Comment: Thanks. It took me some time to install 'pyfasta' for python3 and also the author of 'pyfasta' updated the version for better compatibility with python3.

Answer (score 1):

```
def open_next(ct):
    return open("flnm_%05d.out" % (ct), "w")

in_files = ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"] # or whatever are your input files
ct = 0 
out_fp = open_next(ct)
for in_f in in_files: # your file1, file2, file3...
    for ln in open(in_f):
        if ln.startswith(">"):
            out_fp.close()
            ct += 1
            out_fp = open_next(ct)
        else:
            print >> out_fp, ln.rstrip()
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 1):

My take. There are 2 issues: you want to concatenate the different files, and then resplit. So We do these 2 separately for a clean implementation

```
import sys
from itertools import chain

def file_reader(filename):
    "Iterate over the lines of file, opening it lazily"
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i in f:
            yield i.rstrip()

filenames = sys.argv[1:]
all_lines = chain(*[ file_reader(fn) for fn in filenames ])

# now all_lines is an iterable that iterates over the all input lines
outf = None
for line in all_lines:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        # open new file
        if outf:
            outf.close()
        # take the file number from the '>2' line
        outf = open('out-%04d.txt' % int(line[1:]), 'w')

    # python 2
    print >> outf, line

if outf:
    outf.close()
```

Run as

```
python resplit.py File1.txt File2.txt
```

And get **out-0001.txt**

```
>1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
CGGGGGGGGGGGGG
DEEEEEEEEEEEEE
AFGGGGGGGGGGGG
DEEEEEEEEEEE
```

and **out-0002.txt**

```
>2
AAAABBBBBBBBB
DFFFFFFFFFFFFF
DFFFFFFFSSSS
```

Comment: I think my question is not clear enough. Aplogies for that but I wanted to split a huge file into several parts than cut the carry over sequence from beginning of file2,and paste in end of file 1. Same for all remaining files. Paulo's answer was exactly what I needed but never anticipated that there could be a function for it.